# stage.toDataURL in KineticJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, save-image

Here is how i decorate the stage:

```
every time user drag an image outside KineticJS:
    create a image onto where it is dropped
    layer.add(new_image)
    stage.add(layer)
finally:document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
    stage.toDataURL({
        callback: function(dataUrl) {
        window.open(dataUrl);
        }
    });
}, false);
```

And there is a button with id=save in html

All the image are from my local machine.
Any suggestions? THX!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add the `layer` to the `stage` every time an image is added. What you should do is:

```
 layer.add(new_image);
 layer.draw(); //draws the new image added to the layer
```

Also, your `toDataURL` method looks correct, in fact it looks exactly like this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/) if you haven't checked it out yet.